# Writing to an HTTPRequest object in Java through an HTML form - without an intervening servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, request

I'm looking to write a request gathered from a simple HTML form to an HTTPRequest object in Java; ultimately, I'm looking to reload a page to print out different data based on the selections the user makes from a form - without relying on a servlet. The Java code portion of the JSP looks something like this:

```
if (request.getAttribute("month") == "January") {
    getSomeData;
}
else {
    getSomeOtherData;
}
```

The actual HTML code looks something like this:

```
<form name="month" method="post">
    <select name="monthField"
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
SHOWSOMEDATA
```

I omitted the action field, which reloads the page just fine, but it doesn't seem to be writing to the request; the original code (can't post it - it's for work) has a more complex if/show test, and the page loads with the ("month"==null) case every time, so it obviously isn't posting correctly. What can I do to perform the POST option properly?

Comment: Your question is on Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160443/187824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are submitting your page then use `monthField` as field name as that is the name assigned to `select` input box. Also you need to use `equals` method to compare the Strings as:

```
   if ("January".eqauls(request.getParameter("monthField")) {
```

If you want case insensitive comparison then use `equalsIgnoreCase` method as:

```
   if ("January".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("monthField")) {
```

If you have **set the value in the request using attribute as `month`**, then

```
   if ("January".eqauls(request.getAttribute("month")) {
```

or

```
   if ("January".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getAttribute("month")) {
```

**Please Note:** Putting the string literal e.g. "January" as first argument in comparison is preferable to avoind unwanted `NullPointerException` when `request.getAttribute("month")` is null.

Comment: Works like a charm! For whatever reason, I've been using Attribute so long that I've stuck with it, despite everyone at work using Parameter. And I should've know better tha to use the form name. :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. You cannot set request attributes from the client, only request parameters.
2. It looks like your parameter is called `monthField` in the HTML.
3. You cannot use `==` to compare Strings.

So maybe you want

```
if ("January".equals(request.getParameter("monthField")) {
```